# svg export not keeping line widths

Tags: qgis, svg, qgis-2.4

I just upgraded to 2.4

I have noticed that when I export as an svg, for opening in illustrator, the line/pen/border widths are coming out all different.

For example a line width of 0.25 in QGIS is coming out larger than 1 in illustrator.

Before the difference was only about 0.01 so not really noticable.

My border widths are in millimeters.

Has anyone else had this problem or know how to remedy it?